# SQL "replace" syntax issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, replace, sup

```
UPDATE [Customers] 
  SET [Address] = REPLACE([Address],'123456','02')
WHERE [CustomerID] = 4
```

this code replace 02 on 123456
but i want to change on 2 first digit  is change to 023456 
can any one help me 
Thank

Comment: Are you done try using `substring()`, look over [this doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring).

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [Customers] 
SET [Address] = REPLACE([Address],'12','02')
WHERE [CustomerID] = 4
```

Assuming 12 don't repeat in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put only '02' characters instead of '023456'?
Are you having some situation where you have to put only first two characters, if not try following.

```
UPDATE [Customers] SET [Address] = REPLACE([Address],'123456','023456')
WHERE [CustomerID] = 4
```